# Customizing facebook story appearance

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, rating, movie, rating-system

I'm building a social app for a movie server and want to integrate user ratings with facebook. I've made use of the Graph API but there are some design concerns.

This is how the stories appear now *(sorry it's in Czech but you can surely get the gist)*
[image: Current appearance]

It's a result of this call:

```
POST /me/video.rates?
movie=<movie URL on our site>&
rating:value=<user rating: stars 0-5>&
rating:scale=5&
review_text=<first 2 sentences of user's comment>&
review_link=<URL to the entire comment at our site>&
ref=customstory&
access_token=<valid access token>
```

However, there are some issues our designer is unhappy with:

- Why does facebook add the ASCII stars? Is there any way we can supply our own star picture or at least tint the stars with our site's key color?
- Why is the description of the movie empty even though our site provides the explicit value of `og:description`? (see [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.csfd.cz%2Ffilm%2F9499-matrix%2F))
- Is it possible for us to add the logo of our site?
- The `review_link` is not displayed and therefore cannot be clicked by the user.

Since I'm Graph rookie, I don't know what to do. I've seen some threads about the appearance of custom stories. But my case is different - I'm using `video.rates` which is a common story. Could anybody with more experience point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!
Pete.